# How much to bet on a game of roulette with expected value $> 1$?

Tags: probability, markov-process, gambling

Imagine a game of roulette in which the player has a chance of $\frac 1n$ to win. When he does win, he earns $k > n$ times his initial bet. In other words, it's a worthwhile game for the player, as its expected value is

$$\frac kn > 1$$

The player is allowed to play an infinite number of times, but needs to pick ahead of time a single amount of money $b$ that he must bet on every round. Moreover, he doesn't have an infinite amount of money to begin with, only \$$a$ (where $a \ge b$, obviously).

If the player wants a chance of exactly $2\%$ (or any other arbitrarily low number) of never losing all of his money, what portion of $a$ should he choose $b$ to be?

Comment: Just to clarify, are $n$ and $k$ fixed beforehand (i.e. the player has no choice about them)?

Comment: Also, are you saying that the player's money goes from $m$ to $m-b+bk$ if he wins and to $m-b$ if he loses?

Comment: are you allowed to pick $b$ to be arbitrarily close to $0$? That will be slowest but safest

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you tried?  And how much do you know already about asymmetric random walks?

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated Everything you've said is correct.

Comment: @bgm Right, but I don't want the safest strategy. I want the strategy with exactly a change of 2% (or any other arbitrary number) to go bust.

Comment: @antcam It's not homework. To be honest, I'm trying to exploit an online game the most efficient way... I don't know much about statistics, except for basic combinatorics.

Comment: What you have is an asymmetric random walk with (1) unequal step sizes, and (2) unequal probabilities of going left or right.  [This MSE Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252066/probability-of-asymmetric-random-walk-returning-to-the-origin) seems very relevant although there the steps are fixed at $+2, -1$ whereas yours are $+b(k-1), -b$.  Some of the comments in that thread also seems relevant.

Comment: Also, do you know the [Kelly criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion)?  It asks and answers a different question - what constant _fraction_ of your bankroll should you bet (in contrast, you're asking what constant _bet_ should you bet).  So going bankrupt is not an issue in the Kelly problem (since you never bet 100% of your bankroll), but the goal is maximizing growth.  Depending on your problem context it might be relevant.  It is a very standard way to deal with how to bet in a favorable betting game.

Comment: @antkam I think that question addresses the probability of reaching exactly $0$. What this question is asking for is the probability of crossing $0$.

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated - interesting point... but in that question, you cannot cross $0$ without first reaching $0$ due to the $(+2,-1)$ steps. so i thought it's "very relevant". however the recurrence method may not work here, if the steps $+b(k-1), -b$ are not integers (or at least, rationals). even if it works, the boundary conditions are different since you can jump across $0$... but can you "really"? you cannot jump to negative bankroll in "real life", right? so isnt this question a little underspecified, i.e. you cannot keep the constant bet $b$ if your bankroll $< b$?

Comment: I think the player is done if he can't pay the buy-in of $b$.