# is the game infinite with probability > 0, and if so why?

Tags: probability

Let's say I can play a game by paying a ticket:

- I have $1$ ticket and the game is:

  - I have $1/2$ chance to get nothing for my ticket
  - and $1/2$ chance to get $3$ tickets.
- I play the game until i don't have any tickets.
- Intuitively I would think the game is infinite with probability $ > 0$.
- I tried to calculate the probability of it being finite, this way:
  If $F$ is the event "the game I play with $1$ ticket is finite", then with a probability tree I can see that
  $$\mathbb{P}\left(F\right) = 0.5 + 0.5\,\mathbb{P}(F)^{3}.
  $$
  According to $\tt WolframAlpha$, there is $3$ solutions, a negative, something between $0$ and $1$ and $1$.
  I'm pretty sure $1$ is not $\mathbb{P}(F)$ but I don't know why,

Can someone explain it to me $?$.
I'm looking for an argument to rule out the solution $1$ specifically, if there is one.

Comment: Let $0<p<1$ be the root of $x=0.5x^3+0.5$, and $X_n$ be the number of tickets after playing $n$ times. It’s easy to see that $\mathbb{E}[p^{X_n}]=p$ by induction. Thus $P(X_n = 0)=P(p^{X_n} \geq 1) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[p^{X_n}]}{1}=p$. Now $F$ is the increasing reunion of the events $X_n=0$ so $P(F) \leq p < 1$.

Comment: There are many bounds derived for these sort of games, unfortunately I can't recall the names.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252066/probability-of-asymmetric-random-walk-returning-to-the-origin