# Expected stopping time for a biased random walk

Tags: random-walk

Let $p \in [0,1]$ and $\{X_i\}_{i =1}^\infty$ be a sequence of $\{-1, 1\}$-valued i.i.d random variables taking value 1 with probability $p$. We can consider the biased random walk $S_t$ defined at time $t$ by
$$
S_t = \sum_{i=1}^t X_t.
$$
Let $d > 0$ and define a stopping time $\tau$ by $\tau = \min \{ t \in \mathbb{Z}^+ : S_t \in \{-d, d\} \}$. What is the expectation of $\tau$?

Comment: possibly related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400386/biased-random-walk-in-1d-expected-hitting-time-for-either-edge-of-box

Comment: You are right! I didn't see this question when I was looking before I posted.

Comment: what you've written is a pure birth process -- a stopping threshold of -d doesnt make any sense and it is misleading to call this a random walk.  That said, I'd guess what you meant was that if $X_i$ are iid Bernouli's then $S_t = \sum_{i=1}^t (2X_t-1)$... alternatively you can use the formula you've written but instead define the $X_i$ to be biased Rademachers.  .